# Trying to understand Coupling in WCF (Fairly Easy Questions)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, service

Are there two or more ways to couple and decouple the service type and service contract?

The book I'm reading speaks of coupling and decoupling in two different ways. Am I reading it wrong? I can provide examples but I'm trying not to over complicate this post.

1) She speaks of coupling and decoupling the service contract and service type. Basically coupled is when you don't define an interface for the service contract. You just use the type. Decoupling is when you use an interface as the contract and a type to implement the interface.

2) But she also seems to talk about coupling the service contract (interface) and service type (class implementation) by placing them both in the same assembly. I understand assembly to mean class file (.cs).

ARe both of these coupling/decoupling scenarios? How do you differentiate between the types in conversation? Do they have different names?

I can copy the actual text if necessary. But i was hoping you might understand without all the extra reading.

Thanks!

Comment: `understand assembly to mean class file (.cs).` - incorrect. Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk5f40ct(v=vs.90).aspx) about assemblies.

Comment: This question is not appropiate for Stackoverflow, and yes, in general, an interface placed in the same assembly as it's implementer  looks like you're coupling the "contract" to the actual implementation, because you're tying the interface to the dependencies of the implementing class (such as `System.ServiceModel.dll` and whatnot)

Comment: one of the reasons that interfaces might be placed in a separate assembly to the implementation is so that the interface assembly can be passed to third parties who will be consuming the services. In this way, you can provide them with all of the service and data contracts without revealing the implementation of such contracts to them. Granted, this is what you'd get from a WSDL or other metadata endpoint, but it may be the case that these are not openly exposed to consumers.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried asp.net and waited several days but i got no responses. I also tried DaniWeb. Is there a way to distinguish #1 from #2 types of coupling/decoupling scenarios? I'm not sure if either one is called contract-first or not. I've tried google but could not find anything conclusive. I'm sure there are advantages and disadvantages of either set of scenarios. Right now I'm just trying to classify them. Thanks I'll check out the info on assemblies as well.

Comment: Thanks Russ, that was helpful. So #2 may be called "placing the interface in a separate assembly" to hide the implementation. So separating the interface from the service type WITHIN the SAME assembly offers little benefit? I guess one benefit still might be that You could plan the interface.